# LINQ Distinct Except Certain XML Nodes

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have an Object called `Rate[]`.  This is from a Web Service that returns an Object called `Rate[]`.  The XML for the `Rate[]` looks like this:

```
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:PlanTerm>1</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Prefix>PR</b:Prefix>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR1</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>1/3</b:Term>
</b:Rate>
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:PlanTerm>2</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Prefix>PR</b:Prefix>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR1</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>1/3</b:Term>
</b:Rate>
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:PlanTerm>3</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Prefix>PR</b:Prefix>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR1</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>1/3</b:Term>
    <b:VehicleClass>1</b:VehicleClass>
</b:Rate>
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:PlanTerm>4</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Prefix>PR</b:Prefix>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR2</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>4/6</b:Term>
</b:Rate>
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:Term>5</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Prefix>PR</b:Prefix>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR2</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>4/6</b:Term>
</b:Rate>
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:PlanTerm>6</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR2</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>4/6</b:Term>
</b:Rate>
    ... etc ..
<b:Rate>
    <b:Deductible>0</b:Deductible>
    <b:FormType>AO</b:FormType>
    <b:PlanCode>843</b:PlanCode>
    <b:Miles>0</b:PlanMiles>
    <b:PlanTerm>84</b:PlanTerm>
    <b:Retail>269</b:Retail>
    <b:RiskPlan>RPR2</b:RiskPlan>
    <b:Term>73/84</b:Term>
</b:Rate>
```

These rates have all the same PRICE.

Instead of displaying 1... 2... 3... 4... all the way to 84 terms, I want to group these Rates using the `<Term>` in the Rate.

**Example**: Grouping all the `<Term>1/3</Term>` together.

Note: There are also different `<RiskPlan>` as well: RPR1, RPR2, and RPR3 that needs to be accounted for, too.

I currently have:

```
var ratesGroupBy = from r in rates.GroupBy(r => new { r.Term }).Select(g => g.First())
                    select r;
```

**My question is**:

This is only returning RPR1 and the unique Terms.  It also needs to account for the different RiskPlans and their unique Terms.

```
RPR1 => 1/3, 4/6, 7/9, 10/12, etc...
RPR2 => 1/3, 4/6, 7/9, 10/12, etc...
RPR3 => 1/3, 4/6, 7/9, 10/12, etc...
```

Comment: @L.B - How do I do this? My code isn't doing what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ratesGroupBy = rates.GroupBy(x => x.RiskPlan)
                        .Select(g => new { RiskPlan = g.Key, Terms = g.Select(x => x.Term).Distinct().ToList() })
                        .ToList();
```

Returns list of anonymous type instances, with `string RiskPlan` and `List<string> Terms` properties.